# MySQL IF ELSE true false

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT IF(price == null, 0, price) FROM trips 
WHERE id=9 and prices LIKE "%|s|1|%" and prices LIKE "%|ss|24|%"
```

If `LIKE "%|ss|2|%`" do that price if there is a `LIKE "%|ss|24|%"` doing nothing shows you have to make it `0`.

Comment: Is there a question here? Do you have a specific problem or error? Your sentence is gibberish unfortunately, I have no idea what you're asking. Please edit and clarify. If you want the query to produce some particular results you'll also need to explain your table structure and give us some sample data to work with, and give an example of the expected output.

Comment: @ADyson there is no error code is null I need 0

Comment: As a guess you probably want to use `or` instead of `and` in the where clause, since it's unlikely that your `prices` field is going to contain both those values at once. But that's just a guess because like I said above, you haven't provided enough information for us to know the answer for sure. Also, it _seems_ like you may be storing multiple different values inside your `prices` field, which is a sign of a bad design which is not properly normalised. Read about database normalisation and entity-relationship design in case you need to improve your table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is showing up because there is no prices value containing "|s|1|" and "|ss|24|". I think you should use an OR instead.

```
SELECT IF(price == null, 0, price) FROM trips 
WHERE id=9 and (prices LIKE "%|s|1|%" OR prices LIKE "%|ss|24|%");
```